# Composer install civicrm/cv

Tags: cv

Dears,

I installed CV using composer require civicrm/cv but when I run a command SSH says 'cv: command not found'.

What did I forget ?

Stefaan

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html. If that doesn't help then search the internet for more explanations about what the unix PATH variable is, e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+the+PATH+in+unix

But I'd also consider just [downloading cv](https://download.civicrm.org/cv/cv.phar) and then putting it somewhere that's already in your PATH, possibly /usr/local/bin.

You can also just specify the full path, e.g. /path/to/your/site/vendor/civicrm/cv/bin/cv (or whereever it ended up getting installed).

Comment: Tnx Demerit, the files are where they are supposed to be. (in cgi-bin and the vendor folder)

Comment: Ok, but your PATH probably doesn't contain those folders, so you either need to (a) update your PATH, or (b) download/move/copy the cv executable to somewhere in your path (like /usr/local/bin), or (c) give the full path when running cv.

Comment: I have two environments: the live website and a local Xampp for testing? Neither have the folders you  specify :(

Comment: Those were examples. Where is your cv? Use that for either (a) or (c). What does `echo $PATH` show? Use something in there for (b).